# Disable radio button based on condition in Angular popup?

Tags: angular, angular6

I am trying to disable a radio button if some condition becomes true. Here is the link through which my popup will open:

```
<a style="text-decoration: underline; text-align: left; white-space: pre-wrap;" class="btn btn-flat btn-small" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CancelContinuecopytogroupPopupModel" (click)="passReqIdforcopytogroup(requestDetail,groupData,solutionData,)"><b>Copy To another Group</b></a>
```

Here is my popup code to display this radio button (just added radio input instead of the whole popup source code)

```
<label for="{{radio1.id}}" class="radio" (click)="radioSelected(radio1.label)">
 <input type="radio" id="{{radio1.id}}" [disabled]="solutionData.ReqGroupName == 'some'" name="optionsRadio41" value="{{radio1.value}}" required="" checked="{{radio1.checked}}">
 <i class="skin"></i>
<span>Copy Within this solution</span>
</label>
```

And here is my function through which I am passing details to the popup for display:

```
passReqIdforcopytogroup(nxRequestId,solutionData,groupData){
        this.ReqId = RequestId;
        this.ReqGroupId = groupData;
        this.GroupRequestDesc = groupData;
        this.SolutionId = solutionData.SolutionId;
        this.ReqGroupName = solutionData.ReqGroupName;
    }
```

This is giving me `undefined`, I don't know why. In the above function, I'm getting a value which I'm passing it to disable the radio button. Will anyone be able to help me? Thank you!

Comment: What exactly gives you `undefined`? As far as I can see you're **not** passing the `solutionData.ReqGroupName` at all, isn't it?

Comment: Hi Nicolae ... I tried passing this.ReqGroupName = solutionData.ReqGroupName in passReqIdforcopytogroup() function but it gives me same error. ReqGroupName is giving me undefined

Comment: You did and returns `undefined` because you haven't sent it initially in the click handler. Please look at the click handler: `(click)="passReqIdforcopytogroup(requestDetail.ReqId, groupData.ReqGroupId,solutionData.nxSolutionId,groupData.ReqGroupDesc)"`. As we can see, `solutionData.ReqGroupName` is missing. You should also definitely reduce the number of parameters, by only sending the top most objects that hold references to other properties you need. In your case, you should only send the 3 params: `requestDetail, groupData, solutionData` and then in your handler, use those.

Comment: Hi Nicolae ... I tried the way u suggested but still no luck. kindly see updated question again please.

Comment: Have you tried `[disabled]="ReqGroupName == 'some'"`? And, it seems you're sharing the same `this` across the component that holds the `a` tag and the popup one? This is a bit weird, if the case.

Comment: @ Nicolae Olariu Thanks buddy... problem solved. i was passing param in reverse order. so above code works with the suggestion you given at last. Thank you so much

Comment: Glad it helped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
passReqIdforcopytogroup(nxRequestId,solutionData,groupData){
        this.ReqId = RequestId;
        this.ReqGroupId = groupData;
        this.GroupRequestDesc = groupData;
        this.SolutionId = solutionData.SolutionId;
        this.ReqGroupName = solutionData.ReqGroupName;
    }

<label for="{{radio1.id}}" class="radio" (click)="radioSelected(radio1.label)">
 <input type="radio" id="{{radio1.id}}" [disabled]="ReqGroupName == 'some'" name="optionsRadio41" value="{{radio1.value}}" required="" checked="{{radio1.checked}}">
 <i class="skin"></i>
<span>Copy Within this solution</span>
</label>

<a style="text-decoration: underline; text-align: left; white-space: pre-wrap;" class="btn btn-flat btn-small" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#CancelContinuecopytogroupPopupModel" (click)="passReqIdforcopytogroup(requestDetail,solutionData,groupData)"><b>Copy To another Group</b></a>
```